# Entity Framework "Self-casting Include" trick no longer works in .NET 5/6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I was very happy the day I discovered this Entity Framework Core 3.1 trick:

```
private static IIncludableQueryable<Widget, Widget> WidgetQueryIncludeFringles(IQueryable<Widget> widQuery)
{
    return widQuery
               .Include(w => w.Fringles).ThenInclude(f => f.Bauble)
               .Include(w => w);
}
```

Why? Because `Widget` has a bunch of navigation properties and I want to ‘include’ any combination of them, depending on the situation.  By having composable queries like the above I avoid a combinatorial explosion.

But each of these methods must have that common return type. That “w => w” trick is a lifesaver; I can’t find any other way of converting the query to the required return type. Life is good, until I try to convert from EF 3.1 to EF 6.0.

Now I get this exception at runtime:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The expression 'w' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'

I know that EF 5 has new features for filtering the `Includes` and I'm guessing that the exception is a consequence of implementing these features. Is there some way I can tweak the above method (without changing the signature) so that it will both compile and run under EF 5/6?

Comment: Can you try widQuery.Include(w => w.Fringles.Include(f => f.Bauble)); and see if it works

Comment: Hmm, `IIncludableQueryable<Widget, Widget>` makes no sense, as it allows using `.ThenInclude(w => ...)` which is the same as `.Include(w => ...)`. You should probably revisit your design. Removing `.Include(w => w)` trick and just returning `IQueryable<Widget>` or `IIncludableQueryable<Widget, object>` should be sufficient to compose more includes over it.

Comment: @AkashKava that does not compile; w.Fringles is an ICollection.

Comment: @IvanStoev you're right; thanks!  Changing the return type to IQueryable<Widget> and removing .Include(w=>w) compiles and still allows composition.  If you would like to post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Can't you just cast to `IQueryable<Widget>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole purpose of the second generic type argument of `IIncludableQueryable` is to allow chaining `ThenInclude`. Thus `IIncludableQueryable<T, T>` makes no sense, as the only thing it would allow (if supported) would be `ThenInclude(T x => x.{Something})`.

But note that `IIncludableQueryable<T, P>` is inheriting (i.e.*is a*) `IQueryable<T>`, which is sufficient to continue chaining other `Include` for the initial entity type `T` (the "path" is reset to the beginning).

So removing the unnecessary (and now unsupported) trick and changing the return type allows you to achieve the same goal, e.g.

```cs
private static IQueryable<Widget> WidgetQueryIncludeFringles(IQueryable<Widget> widQuery)
{
    return widQuery
        .Include(w => w.Fringles).ThenInclude(f => f.Bauble);
}
```

and then

```cs
IQueryable<Widget> query = ...;
query = WidgetQueryIncludeFringles(query)
    .Include(w => w.SecondNavigation)
    .Include(w => w.ThirdNavigation);
```